# Changing only the color of the default amsthm styles

Tags: color, amsthm

As the title indicates, I am looking to change the color of the (title of the) default amsthm styles, *and nothing else*.

Is there any way to do this without creating a bunch of new theorem styles, copy pasting the standard settings and adding the color parameters?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why not do that with the help of `thmtools` which cooperates with `amsthm`?

Comment: Would you mind elaborating? I am unaware of how to do this in any way (besides copy pasting default settings + adding colour preferences) :/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is how to do it with `thmtools`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[svgnames]{xcolor} 

\usepackage{amsthm}
\usepackage{thmtools} %

\theoremstyle{definition}
\declaretheorem[numberwithin=section, title=\color{Chartreuse}Definition]{definition}

\theoremstyle{plain}
\declaretheorem[sharenumber=definition, title=\color{Tomato}Proposition]{proposition}


\begin{document}

\section{Elementary Arithmetic}

    \begin{definition}
    A natural number $p$ is a \emph{prime number} if it has exactly two divisors. 
    \end{definition}
    \begin{proposition}[Alfred Jarry]
    God is the shortest path from $0$ to $\infty$. 
    \end{proposition}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: This is precisely what I was looking for. Many, many thanks!

Comment: Thanks for your appreciation. Note I didn't test what happens with crossreferences (I suppose you wouldn't have them coloured).